# Nifi execute script processor

Tags: java, operating-system, apache-nifi

Regrading the following docs **ExecuteScript**:
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.17.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html

Is it known or documented where the script is executed? does it run on the JVM or perhaps forks as a different program on the OS (if I'm not mistaken like the following processor **ExecuteStreamCommand**
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.17.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecuteScript run on jvm of nifi. all languages supported based on java.

for python is actually jython.

Comment: but they all without exception run inside the jvm?

Comment: closure, groovy, javascript, jython - yes, all inside jvm. did i missed anything?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/main/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-scripting-bundle/nifi-scripting-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/script/impl